# Elasticsearch Batch Re-Indexing | To Scroll or Not To Scroll

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-2.0

OK - Here is what I'm trying to achieve.

I've got an ES cluster with tens of millions of data (can linearly grow). These are raw data (something like an audit log). We will have features (incrementally) to retrospectively transform this audit log into a different document (index) depending upon the feature requirement. Therefore this would require reindexing (bulk read and bulk write).
These are my technical requirements:

1. The "reindexing component" should be horizontally scalable. Linearly scale by spinning up multiple instances of this (to speed up).
2. The "reindexing component" should be resilient. If one chunk of data fails during read by one worker, some other worker should pick this up.
3. Resume from where it left. These should be resumable from where it stopped (or crashed) rather than reading through the full index again.

A bit of research showed me that I'd have to build a bespoke solution for my needs.

Now my question is to use **scroll** or **from&size**

Scroll is naturally more intended to do bulk reads in an efficient way, but I also need it to be horizontally scalable. I understand there's a "sliced scroll" feature that allows parallel scrolls but this is only limited to the number of shards? ie if number of shards are 5, then I can only have 5 workers reading the elasticsearch. However, the transformations can be scaled though.

Alternatively, I was wondering if the paging (using from and size) would be ticking all my boxes. The approach is, I'd find the total count. Then I'd be computing the offsets and throwing that in a queue. Then a pool of workers would read the offsets from the queue and reading it using the (from & size). By this, I will exactly know which offsets have failed/pending etc and also reads can scale.

However, the important question I have is does it harm elasticsearch by firing more and more large paging requests concurrently (assuming page size is 2000).

I'd like to hear different views/solutions/pointers/comments on this.

Comment: The problem with paging using from/size is that you won't be able to go past 10000 documents (default config value, changeable, but not advised). That leaves you with scrolling, but the search context kept by the scroll feature is ephemeral (you can also change the liveliness of that context to last longer than 1 minute), i.e. if one of your component fails, it's unlikely that you'll be able to pick up the search context from the failing component.

Comment: Yep, I understand that. But is it a bad idea when I do a large number of (say 5000) documents concurrently? Ex: I'd have 100 workers each fetching 5000 documents with different offsets(from parameter).

Comment: The 10000 limit is a hard one, even if you fetch 10 documents, you won't be able to have from+offset that goes past 10000, i.e. `from: 100000 + size: 1000` won't work

Comment: If you had 100,000 documents, I'd say increase the limit, but with tens of millions of documents, it won't scale.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll need to ditch my offset (paging) idea then. Can a single scroll id supports parallelisation? For example: If I supply a single scroll id and give it to 100 workers, can they see different chunks of data?

Comment: You can do it with sliced scroll, if you have 100 workers, you can use max: 100 and assign one slice per worker, however `you should limit the number of sliced query you perform in parallel to avoid the memory explosion.` Best would be to include a doc-value field in the slice, but not sure if this applies to your case.